# Time complexity of Dynamic Array via repeated doubling

Tags: arrays, big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity, dynamic-arrays

When we implement dynamic array via repeated doubling we simply create a new array that is double the current array size and copy the previous elements and then add the new one? Correct?

So to compute the complexity we have 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + .... number of steps? Correct?

But

```
 1 + 2^1 + 2^2 + .... + 2^n  =  (2^(n-1) - 1)  ~  O(2^n).
```

However it is given that

```
 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + n/4 + n/2 + n  ~  O(n).
```

Which one is correct? And why? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're on the right track with your sum, but you have too many terms in it. :-)

The array will double in size when it reaches any size that's a power of two. Therefore, if the largest power of two encountered is 2<sup>k</sup>, the work done is

> 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + ... + 2<sup>k</sup>

This is the sum of a geometric series, which works out to

> 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + ... + 2<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1 = 2 · 2<sup>k</sup> - 1

In your analysis, you wrote out this summation as having n terms it, ranging up to 2<sup>n</sup>. This would be the right summation if your array had 2<sup>n</sup> elements in it, but that's exponentially too many. Rather, since your array has n total elements in it, the maximum term in this sum is 2<sup>lg n</sup>. Plugging that in gives

> 2 · 2<sup>lg n</sup> - 1 = 2n - 1 = Θ(n)

Therefore, the total work done comes out to Θ(n), not Θ(2<sup>n</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Comment: could explain why you used the tight bound Θ instead of O ?

Comment: Since the actual bound is 2n - 1, we know the work is a linear function and can bound it with theta rather than O.